# How Insert to variable in javascript @Html.Partial

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

> I Want to insert var reportWindow  the render view Report.cshtml
>
> so i could use it to do fast poping like single page application

```
<script>
    var reportWindow = @Html.Partial("~/Views/Main/Report.cshtml");

    alert(reportWindow);
 </script>
```

Comment: What exactly is coming back from that partial?

Comment: Assuming it's html content coming back from the partial, why don't you just put it into the document?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code like below

Note: **You have to put the razor code in between the single codes.**

```
script>
    var reportWindow = '@Html.Partial("~/Views/Main/Report.cshtml")';

    alert(reportWindow);
</script>
```

Comment: i get undefined  in the alert

Comment: What are you trying to to with the partial view html.

Comment: Please put your full Report.cshtml code that will help to find the sollution.

Comment: i want to insert some vars views, so i can pop them fast, this is working the html is inside the var (c#)  @{
         var b = Html.Partial("~/Views/Main/Report.cshtml");
     }
but this not working <script>
    var reportWindow = '@Html.Partial("~/Views/Main/Report.cshtml")';

    alert(reportWindow);
    </script>